# Problem with replying to new messages in the channel

Tags: python, api, telegram, pyrogram

When creating a new message with the `filters.channel` 
parameter in the decorator, the bot does not create new comments to the channel message, if you change this parameter, it will respond to all messages from all types of chats, and I only need channels. I tried using the `send_message` method, but that requires getting the message id already in the chat supergroup itself.

```
@app.on_message(filters.channel)
async def reply_to_message(client, message):
    channel = None
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    await message.reply_text("text")
    print(f"New message send to[{time.localtime().tm_hour}:{time.localtime().tm_min}]:     {message.chat.title}")
```

There are no errors, the bot simply does not return the success of sending the message.